# javascript why is (true)^2 = 3, (true)^3=2

Tags: javascript, binary

In node I happened to use a power operator on a boolean and got some funny results. I guess the '^' operator is implemented as something other than 'power'.

Initially I wrote !!a^3 and got 2. Is it a shift operator or some binary operation?

Comment: `^` is the bitwise `xor` operator in JavaScript.

Comment: If you need to compute the power have a look at `Math.pow()`

Comment: ^ is not used for that, as phylogenesis said, you need to use math.pow, as dystroy says, like this : document.write(Math.pow(3,2)); // that = 9

Comment: In ES6 you should be able to do `a**2`

Comment: @dystroy: I thought that was ES7/ES2016? https://github.com/rwaldron/exponentiation-operator

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I don't know. It works in 6to5 at least.